# Groovy execute().text combination

Tags: gradle, groovy, closures

I've found this code at work

```
def getGitHash = { -> "git rev-parse --short HEAD".execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim() }
```

The thing I haven't understood is the `.text` call, and I haven't found a clear and concise explanation of how it's working. Can you explain to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the extra methods available in [groovy string](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html)

The execute method returns a [Process](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.2/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html) which has a `getText()` method

It could be rewritten as

```
def getGitHash = { -> 
   Process process = "git rev-parse --short HEAD".execute([], project.rootDir)
   return process.getText().trim() 
}
```

Comment: Is .text equivalent to getText()?

Comment: Yes, in groovy you can rewrite `a.setName(b.getName())` as `a.name = b.name`